# How to set text for Static in subclass proc?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, hook

I'm trying to change text of a Static control in another application.

I'm not able to change its text by using WM_SETTEXT from my program. (The target app has some mechanisms to prevent this)

So I inject a library to the target app. In the library I subclass the Static control.

```
WNDPROC wndProcOrig;

LRESULT CALLBACK SubclassWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_SETTEXT:
        DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, (LPARAM)"1234");
        return TRUE;
    case WM_USER + 5003:
        return TRUE;
    }
    return CallWindowProc(wndProcOrig, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


wndProcOrig = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(textHandle, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)SubclassWndProc);
```

I use the Window Detective to set the text to the Static, when I'm debugging I can the program breaks in **SubclassWndProc**.

What I have observed:

1. The SubclassWndProc get called.
2. The string of lParam is always empty (the value is modified by target app)
3. After the function called, the text is still empty (not '1234')

Questions:

1. How does the target app modify the message value?
2. Is '**DefWindowProc**' the most underlying API programmer can use in order to change text of a Static control? If not, what's the best way to change text of a Static control? (Tried SetWindowText, SetDlgItemText, SendMessage with WM_SETTEXT, neither works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `DefWindowProc` is basically the lowest level but a window [does not have to use it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030821-00/?p=42833), it can answer `WM_GETTEXT` directly instead.

Try passing `WM_GETTEXT` and `WM_SETTEXT` directly to `DefWindowProc`.